# Class is present. But it complaints

Tags: java, hadoop

```
 package org.myorg;

 import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

 import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
 import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
 import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;

 public class Write{

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");

        ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {

            public Void run() throws Exception {

                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://10.236.173.95:8020/user/hbase");
                conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", "hbase");

                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);


                 fs.createNewFile(new Path("/user/hbase/test"));

                 System.out.println("File Created");

                return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }
```

This is my java program. I have downloaded my jar from [this site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0201devcorejar.htm). I can see UserGroupInformation class is there. I checked createRemoteUser method is a member of this class.

I compile this program using

```
  javac -classpath hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar -d Write/ Write.java
```

My directory structure contains

```
 jarfile WriteDirectory Write.java
```

I am getting the following error

```
 Write.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        UserGroupInformation ugi =   UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser("hbase");
                                                       ^
 symbol:   method createRemoteUser(String)
 location: class UserGroupInformation
 Write.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
           ^
 symbol:   method doAs(<anonymous PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>>)
 location: variable ugi of type UserGroupInformation
 2 errors
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: The reason could be that you mistyped the method name, or that you pass the wrong arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the version of Hadoop you're compiling against. You're compiling against [hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0201devcorejar.htm). I've just downloaded that, and `javap` shows the following for the UserGroupInformation class:

```
public abstract class org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation implements org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable,java.security.Principal {
  public static final org.apache.commons.logging.Log LOG;
  public org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation();
  public static org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation getCurrentUGI();
  public static void setCurrentUGI(org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation);
  static javax.security.auth.Subject getCurrentUser();
  public static void setCurrentUser(org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation);
  public abstract java.lang.String getUserName();
  public abstract java.lang.String[] getGroupNames();
  public static org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation login(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration) throws javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
  public static org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation readFrom(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration) throws java.io.IOException;
  static {};
}
```

There's no sign of the method you're trying to call.

Looks like you should download a more recent version of Hadoop. (I suggest you replace the *whole* of Hadoop, not just a single jar file. I haven't done any Hadoop development, so I don't know how many jar files are involved.)

Comment: Let me try with the latest one. And I guess i am using hadoop 2.0.0 which is part of cdh 4.7.0. I 'll let you know

Comment: I got 1.2.1 jar now. It has `createRemoteUser` method. I verified it with `javap`. But now run time error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;` I am running with hadoop 0.20. Do i need to change hadoop version also to 1.2.1 for this error?

Comment: @GopsAB: Well yes, you need to *run* with the same version that you compile against...

Comment: Thanks Jon. It's a big change. Let me try again :)

Comment: I ran into someother permisson problem. This is solved. thanks